# qt how to obtain a button that when you click it presents you a list of elements where you can select somethng?

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I am new to Qt Creator. I want to add on my form a button that when you click it presents you a list of names for example (i'm talking about a dropdown button i guess). i didn't find it in qt creator.

Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's called `ComboBox` in Qt Creator, it's in the "Input Widgets" category.

**Edit:**

To select some specific text, you need to find the index of the text, then select that index:

```
int index = comboBox->findText(someText);
comboBox->setSelectedIndex(index);
```

Comment: thx for the answer. i have another question. How to slect the data from the combo box and compare it with a value? For ex if combobox.currentText()=="First" {} is not working. why?

Comment: I've updated my reply with an example on how to select some data. To compare the current selection with some text, you indeed need to use currentText(). If that doesn't work, try to output the result to see if it contains what you expect - `qDebug() << combobox->currentText()`

Comment: i have one more question. How can I create a handler over the combo box?

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure what you mean by "handler". Maybe post a new question and describe the question in more details.